# What does M15 mean?

Tags: articles, translation

Does anyone know what M15 means in the following context?

"And we are again at war albeit with an unseen enemy whose poisonous tentacles have the potential to reach into every corner of our world. At the time of writing, according to M15, the current UK threat level for international terrorism is "severe" – which means that an attack is likely."

The paragraph above is from this article: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/terrorism-in-the-uk/12109626/Its-time-to-bring-back-national-ID-cards.html
In case you need more context
I can't find anything useful on the internet.
Thanks!

Comment: It's a typo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MI5

Comment: It always surprises me to see these typos.  After all, the *I* is nowhere near the *1* on the keyboard, and everyone in Britain knows it should be an *I*, and the article is in a UK paper.  Just how ignorant or incompetent would the typist need to be, therefore, to put a *1*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typographical error.

Comment: @rjpond - It would be very easy to transcribe the handwritten text incorrectly.

Comment: @HotLicks: Not if you were giving even the slightest bit of thought to what you were typing, no.

Comment: @rjpond - Do you have any idea  how many acronyms likely flow though the fingers of a newspaper typesetter in a given day?

Comment: @HotLicks Handwritten? Typesetter? What century do you live in?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The word "typesetting" is still used, even though it no longer involves literally setting type.

Comment: I think there is a natural selection process here.  A typo like "MS15" or "M#5" would have been caught.  M15 and Ml5 are more likely to survive the proofing process.

Comment: @michael.hor257k There's nothing old-fashioned about typesetters, as David says—the tools of the trade have just changed. I'm a typesetter; my typesetting tools are mainly InDesign, Photoshop, and Illustrator.

Comment: You're all missing the point: typesetters used to transcribe the text; they don't anymore. Blaming a typesetter for a typo is an anachronism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is most likely a typo, meaning to say `MI5`.

The fact that the UK Terror Threat levels are [shown on the MI5 website](https://www.mi5.gov.uk/threat-levels) shows that this was most likely a typo. Also, a Google search for M15 returns with nothing, as you specified in your question.